# Randomly encountering com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlInvalidAuthorizationSpecException. Reason: Local security service non-retryable

Tags: database, web-services, jdbc, db2, database-performance

I am encountering com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: Connection authorization failure occurred. Reason: Local security service non-retryable error in my java application. The thing is I am not getting it every time. This only happens randomly. We were doing some performance testing and we can see that we are getting this error only when the load increases. e.g.: when there are 1000 connections/sec, out of which 600 might fail with this error.
Any pointer at what might be causing this error?
Note: My application is deployed in PCF
Error Stack trace:

> org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to
> obtain JDBC connection; nested exception is
> com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: Connection
> authorization failure occurred. Reason: local security service
> non-retryable error. ERRORCODE=-4214, SQLSTATE=28000

- DB2 server platform: aix
- tomcat-jdbc version: 7.0.19

Comment: Please edit your question to show the sqlcode and sqlerrmc that are present in the full exception text, also show the jdbc client driver version details, and mention the Db2-server platform (z/os, i series, cloud/windows/linux/aix etc). Almost certainly you need tuning skills , and competent troubleshooting skills locally. Check the database diagnostics file for more details.

Comment: Which Db2 are you connecting to? See @mao's earlier comment regarding version and platform. How is the connection established?

Comment: I am connecting from WebSphere to the DB Cluster. The DB details are AIX 6.1, DB2 v9.7 Fix Pack 6, IBM Spatial Extender v 9.7

Comment: you have not answered re the *db2 client* jdbc driver version (this information will also be in the __full__ exception text, which you should put into your question).  As you are using an antique server version (v9.7 was released circa 2009) , and you are also not even using the final fixpack  11 of that product, then you are quite  likely to encounter bugs that have been fixed long ago in newer versions.   Your question should detail your connection-pooling configuration in full, versions/configurations, along with the relevant contents from the Db2 server diagnostics file.